# How to achieve Bootstrap vertical Grid Layout with desired item positioning

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have been looking for a way to have a bootstap column appear vertically.

I don't want to use masonry or any other library.
I want card 2 to appear below card 1 on medium to small screens.
What my code looks like:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row no-gutters">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <!-- Card 1 -->
                <div class="card" style="height: 500px">
                    <div class="card-header">Card 1</div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <p class="card-text">Text for this card.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <!-- Card 2 -->
                <div class="card" style="height: 430px">
                    <div class="card-header">Card 2</div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <p class="card-text">Text for this card.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <!-- Card 3 -->
                <div class="card" style="height: 400px">
                    <div class="card-header">Card 3</div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <p class="card-text">Text for this card.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <!-- Card 4 -->
                <div class="card" style="height: 550px">
                    <div class="card-header">Card 4</div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <p class="card-text">Text for this card.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <!-- Card 5 -->
                <div class="card" style="height: 450px">
                    <div class="card-header">Card 5</div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <p class="card-text">Text for this card.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <!-- Card 6 -->
                <div class="card" style="height: 880px">
                    <div class="card-header">Card 6</div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <p class="card-text">Text for this card.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <!-- Card 7 -->
                <div class="card" style="height: 420px">
                    <div class="card-header">Card 7</div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <p class="card-text">Text for this card.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

How My Content Appear:
 [image: Image Given]

I want no spaces (top or bottom) between cards.

I have tried taking 2 `col-6` and adding items normally they appear column wise:

```
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row no-gutters">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <!-- Card 1 -->

                <!-- Card 2 -->

                <!-- Card 3 -->

                <!-- Card 4 -->

            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <!-- Card 5 -->

                <!-- Card 6 -->

                <!-- Card 7 -->

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and I want `card 5` in this above markup to appear after `card 1` on medium to small screens.

NOTE: I spent this whole  day on google in search of a solution for doing this in a simple direct way without using masonry, etc.

Comment: With the first `MarkUp` provided i can change order of each elemnet by using `flex-order` bt still Spaces between each items remains a hassle. 
ANY HELP WOULD BE APPRECIATED

Comment: Is there any specific reason you used height???

Comment: @nazifarashid. its just for demonstration here. that if content or image is of that specific size. other content should adjust automaticaly

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.row_ {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap; 
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 0 4px;
}

.column_ {
  -ms-flex: 33.3%; 
  flex: 33.3%;
  /* width: 33.3%; */
}

.column_ img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
.column_ {
  -ms-flex: 50% !important; 
  flex: 50% !important;
  width: 50% !important; 
}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row_"> 
      <div class="column_">
        <div class="card" style="height: 880px">
          <div class="card-header">Card 6</div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-text">Text for this card.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card" style="height: 450px">
          <div class="card-header">Card 5</div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-text">Text for this card.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="column_">
        <div class="card" style="height: 450px">
          <div class="card-header">Card 5</div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-text">Text for this card.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card" style="height: 450px">
          <div class="card-header">Card 5</div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-text">Text for this card.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div> 
      <div class="column_">
        <div class="card" style="height: 550px">
          <div class="card-header">Card 4</div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-text">Text for this card.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/masonry-layout@4/dist/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/imagesloaded@4/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Try this out! Hope it'll help you to get your desired layout..

I have also included media query in case you need to break the card on small devices.

Comment: Thats Cool. but each is of different height. i've mention in myn question that ' i dont want spaces between cards' placed verticaly. in your solution your cards are of same size thats why they are laigned properly

Comment: @ArslanAmeer Please check now, if that helps you :)

Comment: Thank you. Needs minor adjustments for me to work. Again Thank You.
you have added masonary src link. which i think isnt requried here?

Comment: Yes, you can adjust accordingly. If it helps and technical enough please approve, so someone else may get some help...

Answer (score -1):

This might seem like a weird setup, but try it out.

```
<div class='row no-gutters'>
  <div class='col-lg-6'>
    <div class='row'>
      <div class='col-lg-12'>
        <!-- Card -->
      </div>
      <div class='col-lg-12'>
        <!-- Card -->
      </div>
      <div class='col-lg-12'>
        <!-- Card -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<div class='col-lg-6'>
    <div class='row'>
      <div class='col-lg-12'>
        <!-- Card -->
      </div>
      <div class='col-lg-12'>
        <!-- Card -->
      </div>
      <div class='col-lg-12'>
        <!-- Card -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Something like this ^ 
Just make sure to add the other appropriate classes like `col-sm-12` where they need to be so that this section can be mobile responsive. Hope this helps!

By the way, here is a link to a Codepen where the code is demonstrated.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qGxJRX?editors=1010

Comment: Thanks @AngelGarcia.  But that is exactly what i have shown above in second markup. In this Case What if i want first card from 2nd column to appear under the first card of first column in responsive mode (mobile - medium to small screens) ??

Comment: Ohh, I see exactly what you mean. Give me some time to figure it out.